# How can I return this json object into a string

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON object

```
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "172",
  "mass": "77",
  "hair_color": "blond",
  "skin_color": "fair",
  "eye_color": "blue",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "homeworld": "Tatooine",
  "films": [
    "A New Hope",
    "The Empire Strikes Back",
    "Return of the Jedi",
    "Revenge of the Sith",
    "The Force Awakens"
  ],
}
```

And I need to return a string with the following format: `{name}, {height}cm, {mass}kg. Featured in {film count} films.`
This is what I have so far and it's giving me an error

```
    return `${character.name}, ${character.height} cm, ${character.mass} kg. Featured in ${character.films.length} films.`;}
```

[error][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAciA.png

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the backticks '``' to mark it as a [Template-String](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```js
const character = {
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "hair_color": "blond",
    "skin_color": "fair",
    "eye_color": "blue",
    "birth_year": "19BBY",
    "homeworld": "Tatooine",
    "films": [
        "A New Hope",
        "The Empire Strikes Back",
        "Return of the Jedi",
        "Revenge of the Sith",
        "The Force Awakens"
    ]
};
function getSummary(character) {
  return `${character.height} cm, ${character.mass} kg. Featured in ${character.films.length} films.`;
}
console.log(getSummary(character));
```

Comment: I've had the backticks the whole time. For some reason when I pasted my code it didn't paste the backticks. I'm still getting the same error with the backticks

Comment: What error? ... what is the diffrence between your code and the one i posted above?

Comment: I'm trying to post a pic of the error. I apologize for the lack of knowledge when posting my question